# Need to send a string to another server with PGP encryption

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, pgp

A client is asking my to post a xml string to a third party.  The catch is that the xml has to be encrypted with PGP they have provided me with a public key that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.14 (GNU/Linux)
```

There is very little info online about doing this with ColdFusion that I can find.  There is a project on riaForge http://pgp.riaforge.org/index.cfm that looks like it may do the job but it requires installing on the server.

My question, is installing PGP on the server the only way to do this.  I haven't even hear about PGP in a decade and have never had to encrypt anything with it so any insight would be very appreciated.

Comment: The readme file says it installs the [Bouncy castle OpenPGP](http://www.bouncycastle.org/index.html) jars, which are used by the .cfc. Nothing wrong with using Bouncy Castle for this IMO. It is java based, and a pretty [well known library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bouncycastle) (... and what I was about to suggest before I reviwing the readme file ;-) Is there a specific reason you are looking for alternatives?

Comment: I was just hoping to avoid installing anything on the server but it sounds like I will have to. Thanks for the confirmation that this is the path I need to take

Comment: (Edit) CF does ship with a version of Bouncy Castle built in, but it does not include the PGP stuff, so there is now way around installing something extra (unless maybe you are on linux?). On the plus side, it only requires jars, which are self-contained and easily removed.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the help.  I have learned a ton from reading your stuff over the years.  Thanks for all you do for the CF community